# Tiddlywiki 5 and InlineJavascriptPlugin

Tags: tiddlywiki5

I'm new on Tiddlywiki 5. I try to use the tablesorter.js in a tiddler and was trying to use the InlineJavascripPlugin for that. To test I followed the demo.js of Eric Shulman, but there is no output. It seems nothing is loaded. I tagged the plugin as systemConfig. Is this correct? 
Thanks for your Help 
Jspara

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: 1)
2) The Plugin I copied and named it
InlineJavascriptPlugin
systemConfig

version.extensions.InlineJavascriptPlugin= {major: 1, minor: 9, revision: 6, date: new Date(2010,12,15)};

lookaheadMatch[0].length;
  }
 }
} )

Comment: Then I created a tiddler LoadScripts containing
<script type="text/javascript" <script src="./demo.js" show></script>

Answer (score 0):

TiddlyWiki5 is a modern, completely rewritten version of TiddlyWiki and the old version (prior 5.0) is referred to as "TiddlyWiki Classic". Plugins like the [InlineJavascriptPluginInfo](http://rcorbett.tiddlyspace.com/InlineJavascriptPluginInfo) were written for TiddlyWiki Classic and are incompatible with TiddlyWiki5.

Comment: thanks very much. So it's clear it can' work. Have to look for another possibilty